# How can I make correct output of Locale

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, boolean, locale

How can I make `Locale` output that the language of the passport is Russian, and for each element in the array list, to call the method `isRussian()`:

```java
public class Passport implements Comparable<Passport> { 
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Locale passportIssue;
    
    // c-tor
    public Passport(String firstName, String lastName, Locale passportIssue) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.passportIssue = passportIssue;
    } 
    
    //method
    public boolean isRussian() {     
        if (passportIssue == "ru") {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```java
List<Passport> pass = new ArrayList<>();
Locale a = new Locale("ru");        
    
Passport p = new Passport("Erika", "Ivanovich", new Locale("ru")); 
    
Passport p1 = new Passport("Kemal", "Remzi", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
Passport p2 = new Passport("Ivana", "Bogdan", new Locale("ru"));
    
pass.add(p);
pass.add(p1);
pass.add(p2);
    
System.out.println("Is the passport " + p.getPassIssue() + " russian?");
```

Comment: Use .equals to compare strings not ==

Comment: You left out a `"` in `Passport p = new Passport("Erika",Ivanovich",new Locale("ru"))`.

Comment: If you want to compare your locale to determine if it's russian you'll need to create a seperate locale object to compare it to and use `getLanguage()` with `.equals()`.   Eg. `passportIssue.getLanguage().equals(new Locale("ru").getLanguage())`

Answer (score 1):

## `Locale :: getLanguage`

A `Locale` is composed of a culture and a language.

Apparently you want to compare just the language portion. So get the language code by calling [`Locale :: getLanguage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage()).

The Javadoc warns that these two-letter codes have been changing. So compare by constructing a new `Locale` object using your expected code, and then extract the possibly transformed code.

```
if ( locale.getLanguage().equals( new Locale( "ru" ).getLanguage() ) )  { … }
```

Or if your intent was the culture portion, access the culture portion using `Locale :: getCountry`. But keep in mind that `Locale` is meant for localization usage, not legal usage. The “country” in a `Locale` is a way of representing culture, not a government or nation-state.

Do not compare strings using `==`, which tests the objects’ reference, not the contained text.

Comment: According to [the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage--) you specifically shouldn't do `if(locale.getLanguage().equals("he")) //BAD!!!`.

Comment: @AliasCartellano Thank you for the correction. I fixed the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string with a Locale in the following line (using the "==" operator, which checks if they are the same instance, and that is never the case)

```
public boolean isRussian() { 

     return passportIssue.getCountry().equals("RU");
}
```

Please note, `getCountry()` returns the country code in upper case (see the [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getCountry()).